# Android/COSU: How is the app supposed to auto-run after install

Tags: android, android-for-work, cosu

My question is specifically about one line in Android documentation here.  https://developers.google.com/android/work/prov-devices#set_up_device_owner_mode_google_account . Particularly item #2 where it says

> 2. The DPC is automatically downloaded to the device and launched.

How?

Specifically, what is the trigger that launches the DPC after download while still in the context of the startup wizard? I'm asking because it isn't working for me.

I've got Corporate-Owned Single Use (COSU) application, but I'm getting tripped up on deployment -- specifically the part where the DPC app sets itself as the device-owner.  So far, I've loaded the app in Google Play Store as a private application.  G-Suite exists in the same domain and Google is registered as the EMM for the account. The COSU app is whitelisted and installs as part of the setup wizard... but it doesn't launch.

To the best of my understanding, it has to launch within the context of factory-reset so that I can reset the device owner to the downloaded app.

Is there a specific Activity or BroadcastIntent I should be looking for?  I'm new to Android, so I've been pouring through the TestDPC code, Android docs, and SO posts, but this deployment thing is a pain.

As a secondary query. How would you debug this situation? Its all factory-reset and install by wire, I don't have the opportunity to turn on developer mode and watch logs through Android Studio as it happens. And pushing new builds to Google Play and resetting hardware to download and install has a very long cycle time.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your DPC to be downloaded and launched after an account is added you need to [register as your own EMM](https://developers.google.com/android/work/register) along with your DPC, and [enroll your G-Suite domain with this EMM](https://developers.google.com/android/work/setup#google_accounts).

It might be simpler for you to instead use Google's new [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/?utm_source=so&utm_medium=45518375) which doesn't require implementing a DPC or registering as an EMM.

Comment: What an improvement Android Management API is!  Went through the Quickstart and had an initial profile working in under an hour. I wish I had known about this a month ago.

I think there are two shortcomings, however, that are worth noting here for posterity: 

1. I couldn't set up an enterprise using my G-suite email.  I created the project fine, but setting up the enterprise required a non-G-Suite Gmail (which seems an odd constraint, hopefully temporary).  

2. I will still need to enroll my company as its own EMM because the API is capped at 2 enterprises at 5 devices each.

Comment: Now it's 10 devices per enterprise, but the limit still stands. Out of curiosity: after enrolling to EMM how are you handling updates? We are having issues with windowed mode.

Comment: To go above the 10 devices limit you just need to ask Google to join the EMM Community, and I think the process has been made simpler than before.
For issues with updates can you explain your problem? Maybe open a new question.