# How to create updateable COSU App on Android TV [STB]

Tags: android, android-tv, cosu, android-management-api

I need some help with my app that I build for Android TV.

1. I already make a COSU app for Android TV, but the problem is I need to use adb shell to make my app as device owner. Is there a way to make my app as device owner programmatically? Because I will install my app in +100 STB devices. I tried a method from [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359917/how-to-make-my-app-device-owner-without-nfc-and-adb-shell-command), but it's not working.
2. I still can't figure it out how to update my app later if there is a new version of my app, because like it said in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955252/android-management-api-cosu-on-androidtv), I can't use Android Management API on Android TV and also I think I can't use Google Play to update a COSU app. Is there a better approach to update my app?

Need help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since your app got device admin permissions, your app can update itself silently in background using `PackageInstaller` API. All you have to do is to just download the new apk when available and forward it to `PackageInstaller` which can update and install your new apk.

  Here's a sample if you wanna look how to implement it: author's [link is dead](https://github.com/kosmologist/kiosksample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/kosmologist/kioskappsample/UpdateUtil.java) (after edit [link](https://github.com/czy1121/update/blob/master/library/src/main/java/ezy/boost/update/UpdateUtil.java) - I think they are similar).
- You can't make your app device owner programmatically unless the device is rooted. Here's a list of options by Google to make device owner remotely.
  [Provisioning google dev docs.](https://developers.google.com/android/work/prov-devices#Key_provisioning_differences_across_android_releases)